# proxy config is not working after build the code by ng build

Tags: angular

Proxy config is working fine in local environment

```
"/api/*": {
      "target": "http://10.71.9.82:8080",
      "secure": false,
      "changeOrigin": true,
      "logLevel": "debug",
      "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""}
  }
```

but after build and deployed dist folder in tomcat its not working 
How to configure tomcat for proxy ?

Comment: The proxy configuration is intended to proxy calls when running the dev server via `ng serve`. After you run ng build you are responsible for the web server and its configurations

Comment: how we can configure tomcat for sending request to backend?

Comment: Isn't Tomcat your backend in the first place? If not, what is your backend, and why do you use Tomcat to serve your angular app?

Comment: using sts inbuild tomcat server for backend services and i have deployed angular code to different tomcat (because it is a http server).

Comment: You should deploy your angular app in the same Tomcat server as your backend services: that would make everything easier. Or use an actual http server with reverse-proxy capabilities, like nginx. Tomcat s really meant to server Java webapps, not to be a reverse proxy.